# Getting a error from smartsheet API when trying to delete a workspace I created

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am in the process of learning smartsheet API. This is a Rails application, using the smartsheet gem.

I was able to create a workspace, and verified it visually, using the smartsheet UI, via the application.

Next, I was trying to delete the workspace I created earlier, using the same credentials (API key).

I am getting a 1004 error, specifically, when I process the error, I see:

```
Error Code: 1004
Message: You are not authorized to perform this action.
Ref Id: xxxxxx
```

When the workspace was created, I received the following success message:

```
    # {:message=>"SUCCESS", :result_code=>0, :result=>{:id=>xxxxxxxx, :name=>"My Test", :access_level=>"OWNER", :permalink=>"https://app.smartsheet.com/workspaces/xxxxxxx"}}
```

Any idea why the delete operation, when the create operation was successful?

Comment: Are there any items inside the workspace?

Comment: No, there are no items in the workspace

Comment: Can you include the code snippet that's doing the create and delete?